# I'm getting a weird error in my python script

Tags: python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 17, in <module>
    max_height = max(botmoves)
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'
```

This is the error I'm trying to find the biggest value in a list but it saying something about a ">" here is my code

```
    from random import randint

    points = 0
    botmoves = [-1000]



   for i in range(20):
      guess =  randint(0, 100)
      print('Bot',"guessed the number was", guess)
      print("The bot was",abs(guess-100),"off")
      print("The bot gets",50 - abs(guess-100),"points")
      points = 50 - abs(guess-100),"points"
      botmoves.append(points)


    max_height = max(botmoves) #this is where the error is
    print(botmoves)
```

Comment: Some items in `botmoves` are `int`s and others are `tuple`s.

Comment: The error is pretty explanatory. It tells you that you are trying to compare tuples and integers. Your `points` variable, whose max value you are trying to spot,  is of type `List[Tuple]`. You have to use a custom `key=` to the max function if you want to make it work for complex types. In other words, this will work if you instead use a `List[int]` for your `botmoves` var.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `max` function needs to be able to compare values to each other, and it does that with the `>` operator. What the error is telling you is that there are different types of elements in the list, which cannot sensibly be compared to each other. In this case, an `int` and a [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-tuple).

The reason for that is this line:

```
      points = 50 - abs(guess-100),"points"
```

The `,"points"` at the end makes `points` into a tuple, for example `(37, "points")`. The parentheses are optional in many cases.

Probably that's just a copy/paste mistake from the line above, and you didn't mean to put that there:

```
      points = 50 - abs(guess-100)
```